# Prove that every even perfect number is a triangular number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I know a triangular number is given by the formula $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

I also know that an even perfect number is given by $2^{n-1}(2^{n}-1)$ if $(2^n-1)$ is prime.

Please help me to prove this.

Answer (score 6):

You should use different variables in the two expressions.  An even perfect number is then $2^{k-1}(2^k-1)$  You need to find an $n$ such that $\frac 12n(n+1)=2^{k-1}(2^k-1)$.  I find the right side quite suggestive. Therefore $n=2^{k}-1$

Comment: n should be 2^(k)-1

Comment: @JakeG it is not nice editing the answer you got for one of your questions! Add a comment or something (I saw you did) but then why did you edited your comment into the answer?

Comment: @Vinyl_coat_jawa There is nothing more or less nice about editing an answer to a question you did or did not ask. If you can improve an answer without breaking the author's intent then editing the answer is a good idea. If anything it's the comment that isn't necessary, but considering Jake G doesn't have edit privileges yet and had to go through the review queue doing both made sense.

Answer (score 3):

You could think as follows:

Every triangular number you can represent as follows:

$$
\bullet\\
\ \ \ \ \bullet\ \bullet\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \bullet\ \bullet\ \bullet \\
\ \ \ ...
$$

that is $1+2+3+\ldots +n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Multiplying this by $2$ gives a rectangle

$$
\bullet\ \circ \ \circ \   \circ\\
\bullet\ \bullet \ \circ \ \circ\\
\bullet\ \bullet\ \bullet \ \circ\\
$$

with one side exactly one unit longer than the other.

So if you build such a rectangle and you choose one side of the rectangle to be $2^k$ long, the other side will be $(2^k-1)$ long (where you picked $k$ so that $(2^k-1)$ is prime as required.). It will have "area" (i.e. nunber of dots in it) $2^k(2^k-1)$ and the half of this is always a triangular number.

Since you can do this for any $k$ fullfilling the condition that $2^k-1$ is prime you showed

$$
\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=2^{k-1}(2^k-1),
$$

so 
$$
\text{$a$ is perfect}\Rightarrow \text{$a$ is triangular}.
$$

Comment: I would caution against such a sweeping conclusion (in the ending part of your last sentence), @Vinyl_cape_jawa!  Indeed, it is currently unknown whether an odd perfect number is also a triangular number.  (See this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/234528) for more information.)  We do know, however, that an odd perfect number $m = q^r s^2$ with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv r \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,s)=1$, must be a *nontrivial multiple* of the triangular number
$$T(q) = \frac{q(q+1)}{2}.$$